# Trying to send a delete using ruby HTTParty

Tags: ruby, json, cloudflare, httparty

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
response = HTTParty.delete("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/5746746785687568678785/purge_cache",
            :headers => { "X-Auth-Email" => "myemail@company.com" , "X-Auth-Key" => "7456785476856789567965","Content-Type" => "application/json" } ,
            :body => {:"purge_everything" => "true"}.to_json
            )
puts response.body, response.message
```

I keep receiving purge_everything must be set to true as a response.  Any ideas?

Comment: It might be helpful to tag this question with "cloudflare" or whatever it is that describes the server/service/api you are using. The error is coming from that service, so people who are familiar with it might be able to help.

Comment: Have you tried `{:"purge_everything" => true}` ?

Answer (score 4):

Your Ruby code looks alright, you've only mistyped `true` as `"true"` for the `purge_everything` parameter.

According to [Cloudflare's API docs](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-all-files), the JSON should look like `{"purge_everything": true}`.

Comment: The example in their docs is `--data '{"purge_everything":true}'` which confirms this.